# Accessing a controls value from another form

Tags: c#, forms, controls, label

I made a simple tic,tac,toe game. I have two forms, `Form1` and `frmStats`. on my `frmStats` I have a Label `lblDraw`.
I want it so when the players get in a draw, the label will increment by one. How do I access that from `Form1`'s code?

my Form1 code:

```
if (winner != 0)
  this.Text = String.Format("Player {0} Wins!", winner);
else if (winner == 0 && turnCounter == 9)
  this.Text = "Draw!";
 //this is where i want/think the code should be to change the label
else
  ...
```

Comment: set the modifier of the label `lblDraw` as public.

Comment: i have this but it wont work in form1: public Stats()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            System.Windows.Forms.Label lblDraw;

Comment: no not like that.. Check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all set the Label `lblDraw` as

**In `frmStats` form**

```
 public string strNumber
 {
    get
    {
        return lblDraw.Text;
    }
    set
    {
        lblDraw.Text = value;
    }
 }
```

---

**Form1**

```
    if (winner != 0)
        this.Text = String.Format("Player {0} Wins!", winner);
    else if (winner == 0 && turnCounter == 9)
    {
        this.Text = "Draw!";
        //this is where i want/think the code should be to change the label
        frmStats frm = new frmStats();
        string number = frm.strNumber;
        frm.strNumber = (Convert.ToInt32(number) + 1).ToString(); //incrementing by 1
    }
```

or else simply set the Label `lblDraw` modifier as **public**, which is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

While Mr_Green's answer works I think the corrent way to do it would be to pass your Form1 as a variable to frmStats when you open it:

```
frmStats newForm = new frmStats(this);
```

Create a property within Form1 to access the number:

```
    public int Num
    {
        get
        {
            return myNumber;
        }
    }
```

Then in frmStats constructor you'd have access to the parent form's public properties:

```
    public frmStats(Form1 form)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        lblDraw.Text = form.Num.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: The logic is good but how are you accessing `lblDraw` directly in `frmStats` form here? check my solution..edited after looking your post :)

Comment: First off, he needs to pass information from the parent to the child, not the other way around.  Second, even when you do want to pass info from the child to the parent you still shouldn't pass an instance of the parent form to the child.  It shouldn't have any specific knowledge of it's parent.

Comment: @Mr_Green   lblDraw is on frmStats, quote "on my frmStats I have a Label lblDraw" hence why its available in frmStats constructor.

Comment: @Servy I know he wants to pass info from the parent to the child, lblDraw is on frmStats which is a child of Form1  ;)

Comment: Yes you are right, I misunderstood..  sorry :) but shouldn't the property must have `set` also ?

Comment: @Mr_Green Only if he wants to change the value while on frmStats, to be honest I'm not 100% sure what he wants to do, I just know there is a value on Form1 which he needs for the label on frmStats  :)